# Should this question be on hold? / rethink the closing criterias

Tags: discussion

This question looks valid to me but still it has been put on hold: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/123923/2380

I feel like it becomes harder to decide whether questions should be closed on not when there's edge cases.

Can we organize something (write a wiki) to maybe "rethink" the closing criterias and explain each one in details ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you caught that, I really try to comment when closing. The required code for this (which is what the OP wants) is really broad, and the request is also pretty unclear.

Comment: Well I dunno I feel like the OP just want to have one product per order I agree that it requires a lot of code but I don't think it's broad. The question looks quite clear to me. Which leads to my second question: how can we make the closing criterias clearer ?

Comment: There's a lot more to that question: Is always one order per order item? What about multiple quantities of the same item? Does he/she want separate transaction per item (which is not an option)? And most of all: why in the hell?!? That said, even if a question might is clear, the answer may require quite a lot (as it likely does in this case). As this is the user's first question, I think it's best to have a little more effort (read: "buy-in") on his/her part before someone spends a lot of time.

Comment: Sounds good to me, there's indeed way more behind the question than what it looks like. I still think we should make closing criterias clearer though

Answer (score 3):

That's a really broad question. In my opinion it should be closed. But, if you have an answer for it, I will gladly vote to reopen it.

Comment: Well I dunno I feel like the OP just want to have one product per order I agree that it requires a lot of code but I don't think it's broad. The question looks quite clear to me. Which leads to my second question: how can we make the closing criterias clearer ?